# how to push the navigation bar to the top when click a menu option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3.

```
<body>
    <div id="site-wrapper">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <nav class="nav-bar" id="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul class="primary-nav">
              <li><a href="#">list all </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">list foo </a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
           <!-- empty and maybe hidden(?) at start -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to open this navigation/menu in the middle of my page and when an item is selected the whole navbar should go top and the content of any item should open in the `<div id="container">`

Comment: can you share the codepen or jsfiddle demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/FKeJt)

jQuery

```
$('.primary-nav a').click(function(){
  var tabId = $(this).attr('href')
  $('#container > .hideBox').hide();
  $(tabId).slideDown();
  $('#site-wrapper').animate({
    top: 0,
    marginTop: 0
  })
})
```

Comment: yAP :D thats good to go, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could add an onclick event to the menupoints.
In this onclick event you call a javascript function that changes the css styles the way you want it. eg. add to the menupoint clicked an "menu_active" class and hide all other menupoints....